# ¿Cómo graficar un sólido de revolución con Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas, matplotlib

He usado Scilab pero ahora necesito una herramienta que me permita trabajar con análisis simbólico también y estoy cambiando a Python 3, necesito graficar el problema:

> "Calcular el volumen del sólido de revolución generado al girar alrededor del eje x la región acotada por la parábola [image: x^2+1] y la recta [image: y=x+3]"

La solución ya la obtuve (es [image: 117pi/5] unidades cuadradas) pero ¿cómo graficamos el sólido de este problema? agradecería una respuesta basada en matplotlib pero si conocen otra herramienta de python 3 que solucione la pregunta, bienvenida.

Comment: Ya has intentado algo? Muestra tu código para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trabaje un poco sobre este problema, hice el planteamiento de los siguientes objetivos:

1.- Parametrizar la curva cerrada en el plano x e y.

2.- Llevar la curva paramétrica al espacio 3D y con la ayuda de coordenadas polares rotarlo alrededor del eje x.

Sólo pude cumplir con el primer objetivo, espero que les ayude para la solución del problema. Lo hice en el contexto de `matplotlib` pero se puede usar `sympy.plotting` con `plot_parametric`.

La lógica es la siguiente:

Se tienen dos rectas

> y1 = x^2 + 1
>
> y2 = x + 3

estas rectas se intersectan en los puntos

> **a** = (-1 , 2)
>
> **b** = (2 , 5)

por lo tanto se deben escribir dos pares de ecuaciones paramétricas, una para yi.

Defino en paramétro t de tal forma que obedezcan las intersección **a**,**b**. Si comienzo en

> t = -1 y lo ubico en la intersección **a**

para los valores t = -1, 0, 1, 2 se utiliza:

El par de ecuaciones para y1 es:

> x = t
>
> y1 = t**2 + 1

para los valores t = 3, 4, 5, 6 se utiliza:

El par de ecuaciones para y2 es:

> x = -t + 4
>
> y2 = -t + 6

Por lo que se obtienen los puntos (x , y) exactos de la curva que se quiere parametrizar, es decir; la parabola cortada por la recta, figura semejante a una 'sonrisa'.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Se define el parámetro:
T = np.arange(-1,6,0.1)

# El 
x =[]
while len(x)<=len(T):
    for t in T:
        if t <=2:
            x.append(t)
        if t>2:
            x.append(4-t)
    #print(x)
    break
    
y =[]
while len(y)<=len(T):
    for t in T:
        if t <=2:
            y.append(t**2 +1)
        if t>2:
            y.append(7-t)
    #print(y)
    break        

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))

plt.xlim(-2, 3)
plt.ylim(0, 6)

plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Lo siguiente es cumplir con el objetivo 2 que mencione al inicio.

Espero les pueda servir o que te sirva compañero Javier Cárdenas, aun no puedo comentar directamente. Saludos.