# ¿Como girar sobre el eje x un área entre dos funciones con Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemáticas, jupyter, ipython

Ya se graficó las dos funciones:

> y = -x^2+4
>
> y = x+1

Se logró el gráfico creado con el código:

```
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy.abc import x, y

%matplotlib inline

e1=-x**2+4
e2=x+1
p=plot(e1, e2, xlim=(-5,5), ylim=(-1,7), title="Solido de revolucion", show=False)
p[0].line_color="b"
p[1].line_color="g"
p.show()
```

[image: Area_graficada]

Se busca graficar un sólido de revolución sobre el eje `x` al girar el área delimitada por la intersección de ambas funciones, el eje `y` y la recta `x=2`.

¿Es posible hacer dicho gráfico tridimensional?

*Plus*: ¿es posible *"colorear"* el área delimita por ambas funciones y trazar una recta vertical en `x=2`?

Comment: Relacionada: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7189/c%c3%b3mo-graficar-un-s%c3%b3lido-de-revoluci%c3%b3n-con-python-3

Comment: Otra: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16443/se-puede-trazar-un-sólido-de-revolución-en-python-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es mi solución:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

root = np.roots([1, 1, -3])[1] # punto de interseccion entre las curvas

r1 = np.linspace(0, root, 60)
r2 = np.linspace(root, 2, 60)

theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 60)
R1, Theta = np.meshgrid(r1, theta)
R2, Theta = np.meshgrid(r2, theta)

X1 = np.append(R1, R2,  axis=0)
Y1 = np.append((-R1**2 + 4)*np.cos(Theta), (R2 + 1)*np.cos(Theta), axis=0)
Z1 = np.append((-R1**2 + 4)*np.sin(Theta), (R2 + 1)*np.sin(Theta), axis=0)

X2 = np.append(R1, R2,  axis=0)
Y2 = np.append((R1 + 1)*np.cos(Theta), (-R2**2 + 4)*np.cos(Theta), axis=0)
Z2 = np.append((R1 + 1)*np.sin(Theta), (-R2**2 + 4)*np.sin(Theta), axis=0)

ax.plot_surface(X1, Y1, Z1, alpha=0.3, color='blue', linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.plot_surface(X2, Y2, Z2, alpha=0.3, color='green', linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Genial! Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Excelente aporte, tu respuesta es de gran ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Esas son funciones que van de `R->R` por lo que la gráfica de la función está en `R^2`. No veo por qué quieres graficarlas en `R^3`.

Ahora, no sé si tu intención es graficar algo de la forma `x^2+y^2-z=1`, por lo que podrías definir la función a través de una parametrización con una curva y solamente graficarla en `R^3`.

Un ejemplo de ello lo puedes encontrar acá:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html

Comment: Hola Antonio, no quiero pasar el gráfico facilitado a una gráfica 3D "como tal" lo que busco es girar el área señalada sobre el eje x (la manera de hacerlo con otras funciones también) y graficar en 3D el sólido de revolución creado más no las dos funciones señaladas antes.
No quiero sonar trillado pero en Mathematica se puede hacer sólo quiero saber si es posible hacerlo con Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Comparto mi solución,en la que se hace la rotación alrededor del eje x del área delimitada
por la recta sobre el eje x delimitada por el intervalo [0, 2], la recta sobre el eje y
delimitada por el intervalo [0, 1] o y = x + 1 evaluada en 0, la recta resultado de evaluar
x + 1 en el intervalo [0, 1.3] siendo 1.3 el valor aproximado donde se intersecta la recta
con la parábola y finalmente el límite de la curva generada al evaluar -x^2 + 4 en el
intervalo [1.3, 2].
El código traté de hacerlo claro espero que ayude.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as axes3d

np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

fig = plt.figure()
solido = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x  = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
xRecta = np.linspace(0, 1.3, 100)    ### Intervalos de los segmentos de curva que
xParabola = np.linspace(1.3, 2, 100) ### delimitan el área. x = 1.3 intersección

para = -x**2 + 4  ### Funciones para dibujar la gráfica 2D
rect = x + 1

v = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

Xr, V = np.meshgrid(xRecta, v)
Yr = (Xr + 1) * np.cos(V)
Zr = (Xr + 1) * np.sin(V)

Xp, V = np.meshgrid(xParabola, v)
Yp = (-Xp**2 + 4) * np.cos(V)
Zp = (-Xp**2 + 4) * np.sin(V)

X = np.concatenate((Xr, Xp), axis=0)
Y = np.concatenate((Yr, Yp), axis=0)
Z = np.concatenate((Zr, Zp), axis=0)

solido.set(xlabel='x', 
       ylabel='y', 
       zlabel='z',
       xlim = [0, 2],
       ylim = [-3, 3],
       zlim = [-3, 3],
       title='Sólido de revolución')

grafica = fig.add_axes([0.05,0.7,0.15,.2])
grafica = plt.plot(x, para, 'r')
grafica = plt.plot(x, rect, 'b')

solido.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='viridis')

plt.show()
```

Anexo una imagen del resultado

[image: Resultado de la rotación]